# HTML CSS Field Layout

Tags: html, css

I've had some help designing my field boxes and I was hoping to get feedback on the code. The fields will increase in complexity which is why I thought to structure it this way (image upload fields, textbox with WYSIWYG controls etc.

CSS

```
.error { height: 27px; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 4px;} 
.lft { float: left; }
ul, li { list-style-type: none; vertical-align:middle; }
.ts3 { font-size: 15px; }
.dc3 { background-color: #808080; }
.tc5 { color: #333333;}
.p4 { padding: 4px; }
.r2 { border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }
.r6 { border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; }
.field { line-height:27px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; }
input.field{width:100%}
.fieldwrapper{ padding: 0 5px 0 0; overflow: hidden;}
label{width:200px; display:inline-block; float:left}​
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li >
<div class="r6 dc3 ts2 p4">
    <div class="error r6">Error!</div>
<label field_id="None" for="sender">Sender email address</label>
<div class="fieldwrapper">
<input class="field r2" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
    <p>This is just me explaining how to use this particular field. It is very interesting, don't you know...</p>
</div></div>
</li></ul>
```

​
JSfiddle link
[LNIK](http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/64/)

Comment: You should use [`<input type="email" ...`](http://developers.whatwg.org/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the input with the `placeholder="Email"` is actually an email address, then the `type` attribute should be set to `email`, not `text`.  (Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html)
2. Declare an `id` attribute and a `name` attribute on the email field.  This will be necessary if you want to access the elements or their posted values explicitly. (Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/name , http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id)
3. Once you have declared an `id` on the input, set the `for` attribute on the label equal to that id.  This will enable a behavior such that clicking on the label will focus on the input for the corresponding field.  (Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/label)
4. Use descriptive, semantic class names.  Good class names should indicate the nature of the content, not the format of the layout.  Instead of `fieldwrapper` try `sender-email`. (Reference : http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames )
5. This depends on what HTML version you are using, but the HTML5 spec says that form elements should be wrapped in `p` tags, not `div`s.  (Reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#writing-a-form's-user-interface)

The code that would correspond to my comments might look like :

```
<p class="email-input">
    <label for="sender">Sender email address:</label>
    <input id="sender" name="sender" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="r2">
</p>
<p>This is just me explaining how to use this particular field. It is very interesting, don't you know...</p>
```

One thing you'll notice is that there are less CSS classes.  I have replaced the `field-wrapper` with `email-input` and completely removed the `field` class.  You can migrate the `.field-wrapper` CSS to the `.email-input` selector, and the `field` CSS to the `.email-input > input` selector.

Comment: @JamesWillson no problem, good luck!